# UIEvent detection and handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, uiapplication, nsrunloop

My app has many `threads`, so I do get lot of **crashes** when the same variable is updated and read at the same time.

To solve this issue I decided to use *NSLock* and lock it when the variables are updated and similarly lock it when I get an event Ex: tapping , scrolling the table view. When getting an event I am locking the *NSLock* so variables are not updated, when the app is idle(no events) I am updating the variables.

**My question** how can I come to know whether run loop has any events to be executed and similarly how can i know whether event is handled or not so that I can lock and unlock the *NSLock* respectivelty.

Comment: put an nslog before applying lock and after unlock.debug the code and check for [nsthread currentthread].cheers\

Comment: number of events are mthod calls you have.no need of explonation for number of events you have

Comment: is it possible to get the events queued from NSRunLoop ?